# Calculating surface area of a 3D polygon in R

Tags: r, mesh, rgl

I am new to 3D computation and graphics. I have the following dataset.

```
> data
          x        y        z
1 -83.50855 42.02817 67.87841
2 -79.90784 45.27420 78.96291
3 -70.76262 45.16967 83.27016
4 -63.08391 41.29231 81.74785
5 -70.60881 39.28322 79.47612
6 -80.35512 39.61557 69.02509
```

I was able to generate a 3D polygon using `Rvcg` package.

```
> library(Rvcg)
> polygon3d(data)
```

Animated gif below illustrates the shape of the 3D polygon.

[image]

Now, I want to get the surface area of that 3D polygon. How do I do that?

FYI- I converted the xyz into `mesh3d` using `rgl` package but apparently it's only calculated from two triangles which isn't exactly what I am looking for.

```
> library(rgl)
> data_mesh <- as.mesh3d(data)
> vcgArea(data_mesh, perface = TRUE)
$area
[1] 156.6687

$pertriangle
[1] 46.11146 32.22287
```

Help~ please?

Comment: Is it a convex polygon?

Comment: What is `data` exactly? The vertices of the polyhedron?

Comment: Yes @StéphaneLaurent they are vertices.

Comment: Actually `polygon3d` is also from `rgl`, not from `Rvcg`.  But regarding your question:  your vertices don't correspond to a polygon; they aren't all in a plane.  So it's not well-defined what you mean by the area, unless you mean the convex hull as @StéphaneLaurent assumed in his answer.

Comment: @user2554330, as you can tell I am a newbie in this topic. I am editing the original question, adding an animated gif showing the polygon I'd like to calculate surface area from.

Comment: I wouldn't call that shape a polygon; it's a surface made up of several polygons.  I think a productive approach to calculating its area is to work out the triangles that make it up, and add up the areas of all of those triangles.   I don't know which packages can do this, but you could program Heron's formula pretty easily if you knew the triangles.

Answer (score 1):

If the polyhedron is convex, then you can triangulate its boundary and sum the areas of the triangles to get its surface area.

Let's see. The `cxhull` package computes the *convex hull* of the polyhedron.

```
dat <- "-83.50855 42.02817 67.87841
-79.90784 45.27420 78.96291
-70.76262 45.16967 83.27016
-63.08391 41.29231 81.74785
-70.60881 39.28322 79.47612
-80.35512 39.61557 69.02509"

vertices <- as.matrix(read.table(text = dat))

library(cxhull)
hull <- cxhull(vertices, triangulate = TRUE)
length(hull$vertices) == nrow(vertices) # TRUE => the polyhedron is convex
```

Here the vertices of the convex hull coincide with the original vertices of the polyhedron. That means that the convex hull is the polyhedron itself.

Then you can sum the areas of the faces, and the result is the surface area of the polyhedron:

```
sum(sapply(hull$facets, `[[`, "volume"))
# 338.5752
```